# HTML, JS - Display Loop's Output By Calling <div> From HTML To JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where user may insert the `Total Quantity` and also the `Total Pass` and `Total Fail`. I have created a function where when the number of `Total Pass` inserted, the loop (of entering the pass score) will run according to the iterations inputted.

However, I do not want to have the loop to display the line `Enter The Score :` in the JavaScript function. Therefore, I want the function to call a div from the HTML itself.

For example, I want the `<div id="outputPass"><p>Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p></div>` to be called in the loop function which I have created in the `document.getElementById('btnPass').onclick = function()`.

I have inserted some comments in the code section.

```js
document.getElementById('btnPass').onclick = function() {
  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputPass').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('outputPass');
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  output.innerHTML = '';

  if (quantity < totalIterations) {
    alert("Invalid Input, Pass Value(" + totalIterations + ") Bigger than Quantity(" + quantity + ")");
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalIterations; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      //Call <div> from HTML 
      item.innerHTML = "";
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('btnFail').onclick = function() {
  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputFail').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('outputFail');
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  output.innerHTML = '';

  if (quantity < totalIterations) {
    alert("Invalid Input, Fail Value(" + totalIterations + ") Bigger than Quantity(" + quantity + ")");
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalIterations; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      //Call <div> from HTML
      item.innerHTML = "";
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
};

function togglePass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("passDiv");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function toggleFail() {

  var y = document.getElementById("failDiv");

  if (y.style.display === "block") {
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form">
  <p>Enter the quantity : <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" /></p><br />

  <input type="button" value="Pass" onclick="togglePass()">
  <input type="button" value="Fail" onclick="toggleFail()">

  <div id="passDiv" class="display">
    <p>Enter Total Pass : <input type="text" id="inputPass" name="inputPass" />&nbsp<input type="button" value="Key In Score" id="btnPass" onclick="return validate();"></p><br />
    <!--This Div-->
    <div id="outputPass">
      <p>Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="DONE">
  </div>
  <br />

  <div id="failDiv" class="display">
    <p>Enter Total Fail : <input type="text" id="inputFail" />&nbsp<input type="button" value="Key In Score" id="btnFail"></p><br />
    <!--This Div-->
    <div id="outputFail">
      <p>Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="DONE">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I did not understand, be more specific!

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj Thanks for the feedback. I want this line `<div id="outputPass"><p>Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p></div>` in HTML to be called in the JavaScript's loop function. For example, in the JavaScrip function, ` item.innerHTML = //Call the <div> here `

Comment: you could use `display: none/block` as needed and call the div using the `id`

Comment: I posted the solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can make the following changes to achieve what you are looking for:**

- Initially we're giving an id of pscore/fscore (for pass and fail respectively) to the `<p></p>` tags and hiding them.

`<p id="fscore" style="display:none">Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p>`

- We're accessing them in the javascript code in the form of variables `pscore` and `fscore` respectively. (Make sure they are declared globally outside)

  `var pscore = document.getElementById('pscore');
  var fscore = document.getElementById('fscore');`
- Then in the iterations we can just make a **clone of the pscore/fscore** , give a **class** of pscore/fscore to the `<p></p>` tags and **remove the id** of pscore/score *(to avoid duplicate IDs)*, changing the **display to block** and **append it to the output container** by using the following:

  `var cln = pscore.cloneNode(true);
        cln.style.display="block"; 
        cln.className ="pscore";
        cln.removeAttribute("id");
        item.appendChild(cln);`

  `var cln = fscore.cloneNode(true);
        cln.style.display="block"; 
        cln.removeAttribute("id");
        cln.className ="fscore";
        item.appendChild(cln);`

```js
var pscore = document.getElementById('pscore');
var fscore = document.getElementById('fscore');
document.getElementById('btnPass').onclick = function() {
  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputPass').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('outputPass');
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  output.innerHTML = '';

  if (quantity < totalIterations) {
    alert("Invalid Input, Pass Value(" + totalIterations + ") Bigger than Quantity(" + quantity + ")");
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalIterations; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      //Call <div> from HTML
      var cln = pscore.cloneNode(true);
      cln.style.display = "block";
      cln.className = "pscore";
      cln.removeAttribute("id");
      item.appendChild(cln);
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('btnFail').onclick = function() {
  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputFail').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('outputFail');
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  output.innerHTML = '';

  if (quantity < totalIterations) {
    alert("Invalid Input, Fail Value(" + totalIterations + ") Bigger than Quantity(" + quantity + ")");
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalIterations; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('div');
      //Call <div> from HTML
      var cln = fscore.cloneNode(true);
      cln.style.display = "block";
      cln.className = "fscore";
      cln.removeAttribute("id");
      item.appendChild(cln);
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
};

function togglePass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("passDiv");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function toggleFail() {

  var y = document.getElementById("failDiv");

  if (y.style.display === "block") {
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form">
  <p>Enter the quantity : <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" /></p><br />

  <input type="button" value="Pass" onclick="togglePass()">
  <input type="button" value="Fail" onclick="toggleFail()">

  <div id="passDiv" class="display">
    <p>Enter Total Pass : <input type="text" id="inputPass" name="inputPass" />&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Key In Score" id="btnPass"></p><br />
    <!--This Div-->
    <div id="outputPass">
      <p id="pscore" style="display:none">Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="DONE">
  </div>
  <br />

  <div id="failDiv" class="display">
    <p>Enter Total Fail : <input type="text" id="inputFail" />&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Key In Score" id="btnFail"></p><br />
    <!--This Div-->
    <div id="outputFail">
      <p id="fscore" style="display:none">Enter the score : <input type="text" /></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="DONE">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch, man. And your explanations are well explained. Thanks once again !

Comment: @dionysus02  No problem :) Glad to help